# Expression "column_name" is neither present in the group by, nor is it an aggregate function

Tags: sql, apache-spark-sql

> Expression "d.kualifikasi_kbli" neither present in the group by, nor is it an aggregate function.

I think i undertand what the problem is here. I am running this in SparkSQL and it is complaining that i am selecting fields that are not in the Group By (from Union Select in my example). But this same query runs in Talend. How is it possible? Am i missing something?

If i can't get this to work this way, whats the equivalent of the Group By statement here if i use Distinct? The result will be same as i am not doing any aggregration?

```
SELECT a.*
FROM
  (SELECT a1.ID_BU,
          a1.Nama,
          a1.ID_Bentuk_BU,
          a1.id_bentuk_usaha,
          a1.ID_Jenis_BU,
          a1.ID_Jenis_BU_kbli,
          a1.Alamat,
          a1.Kodepos,
          a1.Telepon,
          a1.Fax,
          a1.Email,
          a1.website,
          a1.ID_Kabupaten,
          a1.ID_Propinsi,
          a1.NPWP,
          a1.no_spt AS modal_dasar,
          a1.Log,
          a2.BU_Nomor
   FROM bu a1,
        bu_nomor a2
   WHERE a1.`ID_BU`=a2.`ID_BU`
     AND a1.`ID_Propinsi`=a2.`id_Propinsi` ) AS a,

  (SELECT b.ID_BU,
          b.id_sub_klasifikasi_kbli,
          b.kualifikasi_kbli,
          b.ID_Asosiasi_BU,
          b.Propinsi,
          b.tgl_permohonan,
          c.tgl_habis
   FROM
     (SELECT b1.ID_BU,
             b1.id_sub_klasifikasi_kbli,
             b1.kualifikasi_kbli,
             b1.ID_Asosiasi_BU,
             b1.Propinsi,
             b1.tgl_permohonan
      FROM bu_registrasi_history_kbli b1
      WHERE b1.id_status='4'
        AND b1.Tgl_proses<'2018-03-01' )AS b,

     (SELECT c1.ID_BU,
             c1.id_klasifikasi,
             c1.ID_Asosiasi_BU,
             c1.tgl_habis
      FROM bu_sbu_kbli c1
      WHERE c1.tgl_habis>='2018-03-01' )AS c
   WHERE b.ID_BU=c.ID_BU
     AND SUBSTR(b.id_sub_klasifikasi_kbli, 1, 3)=c.id_klasifikasi
     AND b.ID_Asosiasi_BU=c.ID_Asosiasi_BU
   UNION ALL SELECT d.ID_BU,
                    d.id_sub_klasifikasi_kbli,
                    d.kualifikasi_kbli,
                    d.ID_Asosiasi_BU,
                    d.Propinsi,
                    d.tgl_permohonan,
                    e.tgl_habis
   FROM
     (SELECT d1.ID_BU,
             d1.id_sub_klasifikasi_kbli,
             d1.kualifikasi_kbli,
             d1.ID_Asosiasi_BU,
             d1.Propinsi,
             d1.tgl_permohonan
      FROM bu_registrasi_history_kbli_hapus d1
      WHERE d1.id_status='4'
        AND d1.Tgl_proses<'2018-03-01' )AS d,

     (SELECT e1.ID_BU,
             e1.id_klasifikasi,
             e1.ID_Asosiasi_BU,
             e1.tgl_habis
      FROM bu_sbu_kbli_hapus e1
      WHERE e1.tgl_habis>='2018-03-01' )AS e
   WHERE d.ID_BU=e.ID_BU
     AND SUBSTR(d.id_sub_klasifikasi_kbli, 1, 3)=e.id_klasifikasi
     AND d.ID_Asosiasi_BU=e.ID_Asosiasi_BU
   GROUP BY ID_BU,
            id_sub_klasifikasi_kbli
   ORDER BY tgl_habis,
            tgl_permohonan DESC) x1
WHERE a.ID_BU=x1.ID_BU
GROUP BY x1.ID_BU;
```

Comment: MySQL has this "feature" where it allows to select ungrouped columns which gives uncertain results.

Comment: so you're saying that the result i get from the above query if it runs in MySQL will be incorrect?

Comment: If you try to select columns that are neither grouped not aggregated - what do you expect as result? It can only be undetermined since you don't tell the DB how to bring down the result of multiple records into one record. The DB has to do something wirth that. But I did not look at your query closely. So I can't tell you what to do. Just think about what your result should be and then aggregate or group.

Comment: *so you're saying that the result i get from the above query if it runs in MySQL will be incorrect?* It is non-deterministic and may be incorrect. Imagine that in a group there exists a lot of different values for a coulmn whereas you want to receive only one row with only one value - what value server must return? it doesn't know.. If you want some definite then use according aggregate function (for example, MAX() for greatest value from all possible ones). If you need in any of possible values then use special ANY_VALUE() aggregate function. If you are not interested then remove this column.

Answer (score 0):

You are not selecting any records from X1 - you are just using for filtering. So there is no need to select all its columns.

Try to write JOINS in order to make your code more readable.

Try this:

```
 SELECT a1.ID_BU,
        a1.Nama,
        a1.ID_Bentuk_BU,
        a1.id_bentuk_usaha,
        a1.ID_Jenis_BU,
        a1.ID_Jenis_BU_kbli,
        a1.Alamat,
        a1.Kodepos,
        a1.Telepon,
        a1.Fax,
        a1.Email,
        a1.website,
        a1.ID_Kabupaten,
        a1.ID_Propinsi,
        a1.NPWP,
        a1.no_spt AS modal_dasar,
        a1.Log,
        a2.BU_Nomor
FROM bu a1
INNER JOIN bu_nomor a2
    ON a1.ID_BU=a2.ID_BU
    AND a1.ID_Propinsi=a2.id_Propinsi
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT b1.ID_BU
    FROM bu_registrasi_history_kbli b1
    INNER JOIN bu_sbu_kbli c1
        ON b1.ID_BU=c.ID_BU     
        AND SUBSTR(b1.id_sub_klasifikasi_kbli, 1, 3)=c1.id_klasifikasi
        AND b1.ID_Asosiasi_BU=c1.ID_Asosiasi_BU
    WHERE b1.id_status='4'
        AND b1.Tgl_proses<'2018-03-01' 

    UNION 

    SELECT d1.ID_BU
    FROM bu_registrasi_history_kbli_hapus d1
    INNER JOIN bu_sbu_kbli_hapus e1
    ON d1.ID_BU=e1.ID_BU
        AND SUBSTR(d.id_sub_klasifikasi_kbli, 1, 3)=e1.id_klasifikasi
        AND d1.ID_Asosiasi_BU=e1.ID_Asosiasi_BU
    WHERE d1.id_status='4'
        AND d1.Tgl_proses<'2018-03-01' 
        AND e1.tgl_habis>='2018-03-01' 
) x1
    ON a1.ID_BU = x1.ID_BU;
```